# Generate sequence based on the value in the previous row and current row

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have the below table having student information.

```
S_ID    Group_ID    Date    Score
12345   1           1/1/2015    1
12345   1           2/1/2015    2
12345   1           3/1/2015    4
12345   1           4/1/2015    5
12345   1           9/1/2015    3
12345   1           10/1/2015   8
12345   2           1/1/2015    2
12345   2           2/1/2015    4
12345   2           3/1/2015    6
```

I want to generate a new table based for few students after adding a sequence column as shown below

```
S_ID    Group_ID    Date       Score    Sequence
12345   1           1/1/2015    1       1
12345   1           2/1/2015    2       2
12345   1           3/1/2015    4       3
12345   1           4/1/2015    5       4
12345   1           9/1/2015    3       3
12345   1          10/1/2015    8       4
12345   2           1/1/2015    2       2
12345   2           2/1/2015    4       3
12345   2           3/1/2015    6       4
```

Rules:

- Sequence should be generated for each combination of S_ID, Group_I
- For the first record, sequence number will be same as the Score
- 2nd record onwards, this will be 1 + the previous sequence number
- if the difference between the date of the previous row and current row is
  more than 100 days, sequence number will be restarted (same as the
  Score for that record)

This is a large table and I am looking for the most optimized SQL. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is to find where the sequence numbers start over.  This is for new students, groups, and when the previous date has too big a gap.  For the latter, you can use `lag()` to calculate a "new dates start flag" and then aggregate this to get a grouping.

```
select t.*,
       (first_value(score) over (partition by s_id, group_id, grp order by date) +
        row_number() over (partition by s_id, group_id, grp order by date) - 1
       ) as sequence
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_date is null or prev_date < date - 100
                      then 1 else 0
                 end) over (partition by s_id, group_id order by date) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(date) over (partition by s_id, group_id order by date) as prev_date
            from t
           ) t
     ) t;
```